# how many times will they be printed and why? i know that: "Alpha" once, "Beta" twice and "Omega" twice but im not sure why

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, fork

here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (!fork()) {
        write(1, "Alpha\n", 6);
    }
    if (!fork()) {
        write(1, "Beta\n", 5);
        return 0;
    }
    write(1, "Omega\n", 6);
    return 0;
}
```

1)or fork1-> Parent and Child1 created. Child1 prints Alpha. fork2-> creates Child2 for Parent and Child3 for Child1. Parent and Child1 print Omega Child2 and Child3 Beta(and Child1 has already printed Alpha once.) or 2) will "Beta" printed twice because there are two child processes (Child 1 and Child 2) created by separate fork() calls, and each of them prints "Beta." and parent prints Omega one time and Child 1 one time?
Or none of the above?im leaning towards the 1st explanation but really puzzled and chatg only confuses me more...

[image: i entered an image of what i think is happening]

Comment: Suggest that you draw it out on paper. The parent forks() the first child, so your diagram bifurcates at that point (and only the child prints "Alpha"... Complete the diagram paying attention to where `return` ends the execution of each process...

Comment: yeah i did that actually. i have an initial bifurcation. right leaf prints Alpha(child1). then two more bifurcations(one for the initial parent, and one for the initial child(child1) each creating a new child(child2 and child3 respectively). parent prints Omega, child1 prints Omega. child2 and child3 print Beta.

Comment: i added a photo of what i think is happening do you find this image to be accurate?

Comment: Looks alright. imo, might be clearer drawn horizontally (like a timeline), with child processes consistently sprouting off _below_ their parent (draw a box/circle for "fork" at the bifurcation.)... Different strokes. ("Flow charting" is a lost art... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On success `fork()` returns twice once to the parent process with the child process id, and once to the child with the value 0.  The easiest way to reason about it is to generate trace that includes process id of the parent and the current process id for each output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print(const char *s) {
    printf("parent: %ld, current: %ld %s\n", (long) getppid(), (long) getpid(), s);
}

int main(void) {
    if (!fork())
        print("Alpha");
    if (!fork()) {
        print("Beta");
        return 0;
    }
    print("Omega");
}
```

and example output:

```
parent: 1217505, current: 1218158 Omega
parent: 1218158, current: 1218159 Alpha
parent: 1218158, current: 1218160 Beta
parent: 1218158, current: 1218159 Omega
parent: 1218159, current: 1218161 Beta
```

Then you just follow each process:

1. Process 1218158 forks two children 1218159 and 1218160 and prints Omega.
2. Process 1218159 prints Alpha then forks the grand child process 1218161 and prints Omega.
3. Process 1218160 prints Beta.
4. Process 1218161 prints Beta.